# Framework Advice

Tags: angularjs, node.js, frameworks

I have a site that was done in CakePHP but I want to redevelop to give it a fresher feel.

The object of the site is to create a document the user can download or email to them. The user will select options from a drop down menus from data stored in the DB, the user is given many forms and options in about 5 steps, and the end product is a file (which I would like to be in word, pdf, txt...something the user will select).

The user will also have the option to select the look of their document from various layouts.

Main functionality required is the ability to spell check, create a preview, create a document in various formats.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing your posted question, I would recommend [angular 4](https://angular.io) alongwith firebase. Checkout [Firebase by Google](https://firebase.google.com) Firebase will provide you the option to mail documents and show dbs etc. very well.

Comment: Thanks so much, i'll look into Firebase.  Can you create docs (pdf, doc..) with it easily?

Comment: Firebase offers a storage for all kinds of files. You can upload you files over there and then you can use, provide download urls to users, and all. Firebase is an easy to use and off course by the brand Google. You also know Google name is enough for all.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark this answer as answered. :)